# File upload using EXTJS and PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, extjs

I upload my file using EXTJS and it's saved in the server
the problem is that I can't get a success function or even the waitMsg is always running
Here is the Code
EXTJS code :

```
 var fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
    fileUpload: true,
    width: 500,
    frame: true,
    title: 'File Upload Form',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
    labelWidth: 50,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '95%',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Selectionnez un fichier',
        fieldLabel: 'Fichier',
        name: 'photo-path',
        buttonText: 'Parcourir'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Ajouter',
        handler: function(){
            if(fp.getForm().isValid()){
     var myUrl = 'php/file-upload.php?idOrganisme=' + idOrganisme + '&demarche=' + demarche;
     //alert(Ext.getCmp('').);
                 fp.getForm().submit({
                     url: myUrl,
                     waitMsg: 'Envoi de votre fichier...',
      success:function(fp,o){
       alert('Sucess');

      }
                 });
            }
        }
    },{
        text: 'Fermer',
        handler: function(){

        }
    }]
});
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
 include("connexion.php");

 $server = "http://localhost/wa";
 $idOrganisme = $_GET['idOrganisme'];
 $demarche = $_GET['demarche'];

 $req = $bdd->query('SELECT idDemarche FROM demarche,typeDemarche WHERE
 idOrganisme=' . $idOrganisme . 
 ' AND demarche.idTypeDemarche = typeDemarche.idTypeDemarche 
 AND typeDemarche.typeDemarche="' . $demarche .'"');
 $demarcheArray = $req->fetch();
 $idDemarche = $demarcheArray['idDemarche'];

 $myPath = '../uploads/_' . $idOrganisme . '_' . $idDemarche . '/';

 $target_path = utf8_decode($myPath);
 mkdir($target_path, 0705);
 echo 'OK';
 if(isset($_FILES)){
  echo 'OK';
  $temp_file_name = utf8_decode($_FILES['photo-path']['tmp_name']);
  $original_file_name = utf8_decode($_FILES['photo-path']['name']);

  // Find file extention
  $ext = explode ('.', $original_file_name);
  $ext = $ext [count ($ext) - 1];

  // Remove the extention from the original file name
  $file_name = str_replace ($ext, '', $original_file_name);

  $new_name = $target_path . '[' . utf8_encode($file_name) . $ext;
  chmod($new_name, 705);

  if(move_uploaded_file ($temp_file_name, $new_name)) {
   if($idDemarche!=''){
    $length = strlen($new_name);
    $path = $server . substr($new_name,2,$
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO liens(idDemarche, lien) values(:idDemarche, :lien)');
    $req->execute(array('idDemarche' => intVal($idDemarche), 'lien' => $path));
    echo "OK";
   }
  } 
  else {
   echo "error";
  }
  echo 'message';
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem. Found out that you need to set the content type to "text/html" on the page that handles the file upload. :-(

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

If you [read the documentation for Ext.data.Connection,](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/) you will see that

> The server response is parsed by the browser to create the document for the IFRAME. If the server is using JSON to send the return object, then the Content-Type header must be set to "text/html" in order to tell the browser to insert the text unchanged into the document body.

Took me a while to find this, but as I came across your question, someone else might do to with a similar problem!

hopefully this will help them!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a JSON response for file uploads, in your php code use either:

```
echo "{success: true}";
```

or

```
echo "{success: false}";
```

For further reference please refer to: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Action.html#cls-Ext.form.Action.Submit

You can also return custom errors which will help you handle the different states you are using in your code.

Comment: It don't work, my upload form is in a window that I show when I click on a button, can this be the problem ???

Comment: No- provided the PHP script that handles the upload on the server side ONLY returns the JSON, that should be enough (i.e. the only thing the PHP should return is, i.e. '{success: true}'.